# Why was the Gypsy so annoyed about being asked if they have tonic and gin at the bar?

Tags: serhiy-zhadan, ukrainian-language, voroshilovgrad

When Herman first went to go see Olga about the state of his brother's gas station, they went to a bar neither of them had been in in quite awhile. They had the following rather odd exchange with one of the employees:

> The Gypsy came over.
> "Do you have any gin and tonic?" Olga asked.
> "No," he replied firmly.

Indeed, Olga was slightly flustered by his reaction. Why did he react that way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gin and tonic is a very popular drink, and its ingredients are also used in many other drinks.  It is odd and unusual for a bar to be unable to provide it.  Olga is probably flustered at having what she regarded as a routine order be impossible; it was a rhetoric question, not expecting the answer "No."

Furthermore, it's probable that he's been asked for one a lot.  Having to say they didn't over and over and over would add firmness to his response, to discourage argument.